# Scaling viewports smaller than a specific value in a responsive layout

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, responsive-design, viewport

I'm working on a responsive layout that uses the following bit of code:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">`

The designer built layouts for Large Desktop (1370px wide), Small Desktop (990px) and Tablet (620px). The assumption is that Mobile (<620px) will use the Tablet version but scale it.

How would I do that, though? Because the viewport's width is set to `device-width`, it loads the smallest stylesheet but doesn't scale it.

**tl;dr -- Is there any way to tell a mobile browser to disregard the `width=device-width` value and instead scale the website to fit when the viewport is smaller than a certain value?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First off this isn't really the best approach for a typical responsive design. If you build mobile first and set the widths to % then it will avoid any issues that you might be having because the content will scale to the device width.

If you really want to go down the other path though you could alter the meta viewport element using javascript and use [enquire.js](http://wickynilliams.github.com/enquire.js/) to dictate when that would occur....

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:619px)", {

    match : function() {
$('meta[name=viewport]').attr(
 'content',
 'width=620; initial-scale=1.0'
);

},      

    unmatch : function() {
$('meta[name=viewport]').attr(
 'content',
 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
);
},
});
```

Please note that

1. This is not tested
2. My jquery/javascript is terrible but should give you enough to keep going.